# how to filter Collection (Firebase) by uid in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problems trying to get one specific value from Firebase.

I'm using `.whereField('uid', isEqualsTo: "givenID")` in `Collection("something")` but I'm not getting any response. I know in Flutter the field is 'uid' but for some reason in swift isn't the same. I'll appreciate your help maybe with the name of the field or another way to bring the value with the given id in Firebase.

[image: First attempt]

Useful information

- Swift 5
- XCODE 11.4.1

Comment: Please, read the Firebase documentation for Swift. See your Firebase Database to see if the field you are looking for exists too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution". Create a field in my Collection called "id" and assigning it with the same id from the document. Now I can just
db.collection("yourCollection").whereField("id", isEqualsTo: "givenID").

Not the best solution, but a solution is a solution.

UPDATE

I found it.

```
db.Collection("yourCollection").document("GivenID")
```

This bright you the subCollection

And that's all

Comment: It's great you found an answer but what's posted here is not related to the question that was asked. The question states you're trying to get one specific value and the code presented (in the question) will query the usarious collection for all documents that had a field DocumentID equal to idUser. The code in this answer doesn't do that - the code in this answer reads a specific document via a documentID within yourCollection. Also there is no Subcollection involved. Maybe the question was 'how do I read a specific document by it's documentID?